# How to set admob custom targeting

Tags: android, admob

I would like to an admob banner in my app, showing ads in specific categories (every device would have a specific categories).
For example, app installed on one device would show only music, other would show only travel, etc.

I looked in [Google developers guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner?hl=zh-tw#custom_targeting) and [PublisherAdRequest API](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/doubleclick/PublisherAdRequest.Builder.html#addNetworkExtras(com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.NetworkExtras)) and notice the following example:

```
    // Example: Pass custom targeting "Age=25", "Color=Blue,Green,Red"
private PublisherAdRequest createRequest() {
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("Age", "25");
  bundle.putString("Color", "Blue,Green,Red");
  return  new PublisherAdRequest.Builder()
      .addNetworkExtras(new AdMobExtras(bundle))
      .build();
}
```

My question is - What keywords are available for me? 
If I would like to get only Music and travel related ads, what keywords should I use?

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I believe these categories you can set on admob dashboard. you don't have to configure such settings in your code

Comment: Configuring it on admob dashboard will not give me device specific categiries